# Error in submitting UWP Creators Program game

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

I am trying to develop a UWP game with Unity and publish it to the Xbox through the Creators Program. However, after filling in all the necessary sections (and they all say "Passed"), the Submit button is disabled and a message above it reads "This product requires a valid Xbox Live configuration. Address any configuration errors before submitting to certification." I ran the xbox live service configuration in Unity, and it created the XboxServices.config file. I double checked the values that were in it and the SCID and TitleId match up, and the XboxCreatorsProgram value is set to true. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you enabled the Xbox live service in Dev Center? If so, it's hard to tell the real cause for the message according to your description. I'm trying to report it to related team to see if there is any possible issue and will keep you posted.

Comment: Yes, Xbox Live service is enabled in Dev Center. When I click "Settings" for this, I have both Xbox and Desktop selected.